# trying to get first item in collection returns NULL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've previously done a lot of development using Stored Procs to do all the data modifications.

But I now need to use LINQ To SQL and a basic fundamental task has me stumped.

I have a class called Book (Title, Author , etc). A number of books are instantiated and added to 
public ObservableCollection Books

So far so good, I can see that it holds valid books in its collection.

I have a function **DeleteOldestBook()** which simply gets the first Book in Books , and deletes. This is where I run into trouble.

I try and select

```
Book BookToDelete = Books.Take(1) as Book;
```

but it always returns NULL.

I've managed a hacky workaround  :

```
var AllBooks = from BookToDelete in Books select BookToDelete;
foreach (Book BookToDelete in AllBooks)
{ 
    //  BookToDelete.dostuff takes place ... 
    break; // only do 1
}
```

But this is awful and I know there's something simple I've missed.

Any ideas from the LINQ experts? Let me know you if you need more code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a `Books.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: First, verify using the debugger that you can see one book in Books.  Second, add a watch on Books.Take(1) and make sure it can be cast to a Book, since "as" casting returns null if the cast fails.  Another way to test the cast is to change the line to Book BookToDelete = (Book)Books.Take(1);

Comment: there are several good answers - be sure to accept the one that worked for you as the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I marked the first one as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) will return a collection with n elements in it.  You still need to iterate over that collection.  In your case, the collection size is 1.

[`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) will return the first item in the collection.

**Extra Credit**

If your collection is not already sorted use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
Book bookToDelete = Books.OrderBy(b => b.SomeDate).First();
```

Comment: Extra extra credit, don't assume there are any books. Use .FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 10):

`Take()` returns an `IEnumerable<Book>`. As such, your attempt to cast it into a `Book` fails, returning a null value.

Use `Books.First()` or `Books.FirstOrDefault()` instead.

*Clarification for Nitpickers*: `Take()` may actually return an `IQuerable<Book>` if `Books` came directly from a `DataContext`.

Answer (score 6):

just use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx):

```
var firstBook = Books.FirstOrDefault();
```

If there is no book in the collection, `firstBook` will be `null`, otherwise it will be set to the first item.

*Typically* you would want the first book by *some* criteria though, if so just use an appropriate `Where` clause beforehand:

```
var firstThriller = Books.Where(b => b.Type == "Thriller")
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Answer has the wrong reason for the error: take doesn't return a Book.

Comment: I don't see where I give the `wrong reason` for the error - in fact I didn't get into why OP's code is not working, just what to do instead. I admit that's an omission, but anything stated here is not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said you omitted it.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use

```
Books.First();
```

Instead of

```
Take(1);
```

The Take Extension method returns `IQueryable<T>` and you're trying to cast as `T` (`Book`).  This is why you always get null.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you missed the `First()` extension method:

```
Book BookToDelete = Books.First();
```

Note that `Take(int)` returns a sequence of Books (`IQueryable<T>`) - even if that sequence contains just one item in your case. As there is no conversion from `IQueryable<T>` to `T`, `as` will return null.

Answer (score 1):

`Take` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` containing a single element, what you want is:

```
Books.FirstOrDefault();
```

Which returns the first element (or `null` if `Books` is empty).